# value of my List is changing when i delete text from TextField Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a list that i want to search in (I remove the values that don't match my search), I write the search word in a TextField and save the initial list in order to show it again when the user deletes the search word (or want to search for another thing) .
i can save the list in a variable but the issue is when I start deleting the search word the value of my initial list becomes the same that the list I show for the search !

```
onChanged: (val) {
 //i save the list before doing any change here
   if (_initList == null) _initList = myList;
// this part works fine
    if (val.length > 2)
         setState(() {
             myList.removeWhere((element) => !element
              .getName()
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(val.toLowerCase()));
           });
// when i’m in the else, when i try to print _initList value i find that it’s the same as myList
// the value of _initList is not changing anywhere else in the code
     else {
          setState(() {
                myList = _initList;
            });
      }
 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do this

```
if (_initList == null) _initList = myList;
```

both variables will point to the same list. changes to one list will also change the other, because they are in fact the same list. What you want to do is safe a copy of the list in it. You can do it by calling `toList()` on it, like

```
if (_initList == null) _initList = myList.toList();
```